# ReflectionTestUtils.setField on resource spring 5.2.2 - jersey 2

Tags: java, spring, jersey, spring-test

```
@Path("/lala")
@Component
public class Resource {
    @Autowired
    private Idservice idService;

    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
}
```

in test set httpRequest to MockHttpServletRequest:

```
MockHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
Resource resource = getContext().getBean(Resource.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(resource, "httpRequest", httpServletRequest);
```

in the test:

```
resource = Resource@1234 
httpRequest = MockHttpServletRequest@1111
idService = $Proxy333@3333
```

when calling the api resource httpRequest gets another object.
resource object has the same address as in the test. 
on resource:

```
resource = Resource@1234 
httpRequest =$Proxy222@2222
idService = $Proxy333@3333
```

why httpRequest not stay with  MockHttpServletRequest ?

it worked on spring 4.1.5 and jersey 1

Comment: Because JAX-RS will inject the current request which isn't your mock. You are trying to shoehorn mocking into an integration test. Either write a proper unit test (outside the scope of Spring just the objects yuo need) or write a proper integration test. You are now creating some hybrid.

Comment: Got you, do you know why it worked with spring 4.1.5 and jersey 1?

Comment: Nope as I know too little of Jersey in that regard.